# バイナリデータに対してのデコードプログラムの作成

Tags: c, テキストファイル, バイナリファイル, file

こんにちは

私は今、加速度センサからのデータをSDカードに保存しようとしています。
測定データをすぐにバイナリデータとしてSDカードに書き込み、文字化けのような状態となっています。
これをデコードして数値として読める状態にしたいです。 
一言でいうと、バイナリデータを保存してあるテキストファイルに対してデコードプログラムを適用するということをしたいです。 
例としてバイナリデータを保存してあるテキストファイルを添付します。
タブで区切られており、加速度センサの出力値として
左から時間、XH_data、XL_data、YH_data、YL_data、ZH_data、ZL_data
の7つのデータが1つの行となり、構成されています。 
どのようなデコードプログラムを適用すれば読めるようになるのでしょうか？
分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら是非ご教授お願い致します。

```
o<  ﾀ @    ﾀ @    ﾀ @     @     @      @
```

Comment: バイナリデータが「テキストファイルに」「タブで区切られて」いると言うだけで **恐ろしく奇妙なデータ形式なので、先にデータを保存する部分を修正した方が良い** と言えます。タブコードというのは「1バイトのバイナリデータ」でしかありませんから、不定長のデータを扱う場合など、元のデータを復元できなくなる場合もあります。(今回は各データ固定長だと思いますが。)またバイナリデータを読み込むためには各データが何バイトでどんな形式で保存されているのかの情報が必要となります。(例えば数値なら「4バイトの符号付きLittle Endian」とか。) **「時間」、`XH_data`〜`ZL_data`はどんな形式ですか?** 特にセンサーから読み込まれたデータは単なる整数値ではなくオフセット表現やスケール表現になっていることが多く、時間もデバイスごとの独自形式で表現されていることが多いです。バイナリデータを保存しているのですから、テキストファイルとして表示させたものを表示しても意味はありません。バイナリファイルとして16進ダンプを示せば感のいい人なら形式がわからなくてもなんとかできるかもしれません。「バイナリデータを保存」するのに使ったコードをお示しいただくのも回答を書くための情報になります。ご自身の質問は編集できるはずですので、必要な情報を追記してください。

Comment: センサーの型番等が分かると回答のヒントになるのかなと思います (過去質問と同じものでしょうか？)